# Xcrun missing, xcode command line tool not fixing

Tags: macos, homebrew, xcrun, xcode-command-line-tools

Having an odd Mac OS issue. I'm on a mid-2015 McBkPro running High Sierra 10.13.3.

Haven't coded on a new project in a while (been busy on my last projects for most of the past year); now I tried starting up a new project and well none of my commands seem to work...

I always get `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`. seemed pretty straight forward, x-code cmd line tool missing... Except installing it seems to not work/have no effect.

I enter: `xcode-select --install`, press install, agree to the agreement, it downloads, installs, gives me a nice `The software was installed` but if I try any command again (like `brew update` or `brew upgrade`); I get the same error... (tried rebooting, no effect)

Any clues? (all I could find googling were people saying "install x-code cmd line tool")

Comment: I think you'll have better luck asking this question on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) or even on the [home-brew discourse site](https://discourse.brew.sh) - it's not really a programming question in [the Stackoverflow definition](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks Craig, asked on AskDifferent and got some help, ended up finding the solution myself. Will add a solution below just so there is an answer to this if someone ever has the same issue. Have a good day! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, After a full day of attempts, re-installing homebrew and all... found a solution which I should have tried a lot earlier in all honesty. Leaving it here if anyone else has the same problem in the future:

Doing `xcode-select --install` showed everything as being installed correctly but I just couldn't confirm that anywhere. I downloaded the CLT as a pkg from the apple developer website (https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and installed it the old fashioned way. CLT is now installed and homebrew is detecting it just fine.

Brew Config now:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.5.14
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 7fd6210127f088b6ee8708a1d7f4ec2df3fc5bb4
Last commit: 6 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: 1f9ba958e21dce9673b932cfc1f55dd155f0df69
Core tap last commit: 31 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
CPU: octa-core 64-bit haswell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.3.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 9.1 build 902
Git: 2.8.1 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.54.0 => /usr/bin/curl
Java: 1.8.0_77
macOS: 10.13.3-x86_64
CLT: 9.3.0.0.1.1521514116
Xcode: N/A
XQuartz: N/A
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I'm having the exact same issue with brew and I'm working on fixing my Xcode installation right now. I never would have found this link. Hopefully this will fix my issue with command line tools.